# Appropriate Use of Being

Tags: grammar, being

**Please have a look on this paragraph**

"There were some residential quarters in the elevated land area **being occupied** by government employee. The surrounding was bushy having some trees and commonly inaccessible to the area. One day, a person could notice some skeletal remains lying on the ground under a tree and reported to the police. On having the information, the police and forensic team visited the spot. The spot was almost undisturbed and as per statement of the informer, skull and some bones were found lying under the tree at one place on the ground. On further search, a pair of plastic slipper was kept near the foot of the tree, apparently kept before climbing in bare foot. On further search, a long bone, a torn pant (wearing apparel) and a portion of rope **being tied** with one of its end in a branch of the tree were also noticed. All the items were brought down for further examination to derive the information contained in them. In course of examination, one cell phone was also found kept inside the pocket of the damaged pant. All the physical evidence was collected for further investigation in this case."

This paragraph is describing a past event.
Then why **BEING OCCUPIRD** and **BEING TIED** is used in this context?[image]

Comment: *Being* does not have a tense of its own, and so can be used in any context whatsoever, past, present or future. You seem to have no issues with *having, lying, climbing* in the same paragraph. As well you shouldn't.

Comment: @Yosef that is not what the question is about at all. Nobody is trying to emulate anyone. People are trying to understand basic English. In which case its being basic only helps.

Comment: Sir I m very poor in english ...I am very eger to learn it ...I have to translate everything  into my mother tongue to understand it ...Sometimes it become very tuff for  me to understand to the letter...

Comment: Thank you so much RegDwigHt sir....Can u please elaborate?

Comment: See [my recent answer about tenses](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/549830/142322).

Answer (score 0):

If the OP can relate the following to what he is looking for...!

//There were some residential quarters in the elevated land area being occupied by government employee.// Here, it means, "...elevated land area which is being occupied by government employee..."  In other words, it can be written in the active voice as, "There were some residential quarters in the elevated land area that the government employee is occupying."

Grammatical interpretations apart, it means that the land are is in an 'occupied stage' by the govt employee.

BEING is the continuous form of BE

He is being…(It is like, He is studying)/  He was being…(It is like, He was studying)  /  He will be (being)…(It is like, He will be studying)

He is being a doctor…; He was being a doctor…; He will be (being) a doctor…

IN PASSIVE VOICE:  is carrying – is being carried

He is hunting a wild cat. / A wild cat is being hunted by him.

I am writing a letter. / A letter is being written by me.

AS PARTICIPLES

Being a police officer, I had to take action.
Being a student, I had to study a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**Being occupied** and **being tied** are used as participles in these sentences.

As I said in [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/264353/117108) answer, the participles are not only present participles and past participles, but various **participial constructions** (in that answer I called them *compound participles*) that can be used pretty much in the same way as present and past participles. Your **being occupied** and **being tied** are examples of such participial constructions too.

In your example these participles (more precisely, participial phrases in which these participles are headwords) are used to get rid of the relative clauses and thus make the sentence shorter (as is the case with the question to which I answered with the answer mentioned above). For example, the sentence

> There were some residential quarters in the elevated land area being occupied by government employee.

is a shorthand for a "full" sentence that is using a relative clause:

> There were some residential quarters in the elevated land area that was being occupied by government employee.

So, here the participle phrase *being occupied by government employee* is used instead a relative clause *that was being occupied by government employee*.

Regarding the fact that this paragraph is about the past - there are no restrictions to which time the sentence should refer to be able to contain the participle. The time of a participle is understood to be the same as the time of the main clause of the sentence in which this participle is used. In your examples this time is past.

Comment: Many thanks Russo Sir.

Comment: Many thnx @Russo  sir.           But what is about "Being Tied" ? Act of tying of rope was finished well before they found it. Then why BEING is used????      Can we use simply "Tied" instead of "Being Tied"? I shall be great ful to u if u answer my question.

Comment: @KaushikSen I am not a native speaker, so I cannot answer this question, since it refers more to common/uncommon usage of a word... As for me, "tied" would be really more appropriate here, so I don't know why "being tied" is used. The only thing I wanted to say in my answer is that it is **grammatically** absolutely correct to use *being tied* in this sentence, but I cannot estimate the **semantic** appropriateness of using this.